# Adding time band as year to NDVI composite

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, time, date

I try to add time band to my NDVI time-series and using this function (took it from developers guide), for regression calculation.

It looks like script is working but magnitude of slopes is extremely high.
So, I,d like to add time-band as year, not as a milliseconds, because I am working with yearly composites, how can I to do so?

```
// This function adds a time band to the image.
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  // Scale milliseconds by a large constant to avoid very small slopes
  // in the linear regression output.
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(1e18));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by converting the timestamp of the image to a date object and then just requesting the "year" property.

Modify your code as follows.

```
// This function adds a time band to the image.
var createTimeBand = function(image) {

  // get the system:time_start property and extract the year
  var timestamp = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).get('year')

  return image.addBands(timestamp);
};
```